# Xdebug v3.0.2 with PHP v8.0.0

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, php-8

I just have migrated to php v8.0.0 with XAMPP v3.2.4. But Xdebug is not working. Execution is not stopping on breakpoints.

My installation instructions-

```
Download php_xdebug-3.0.2-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
Move the downloaded file to \xampp\php\ext
Update D:\xampp\php\php.ini and change the line
zend_extension = \xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.2-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
Restart the webserver
```

Here is the installation summary-

```
Xdebug installed: 3.0.2
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes
Compiler: MS VS16
Architecture: x64
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 8.0.0
Zend API nr: 420200930
PHP API nr: 20200930
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
OPcache Loaded: no
Configuration File Path: no value
Configuration File: D:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: \xampp\php\ext
```

php.ini

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
zend_extension = D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.2-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
```

VS Code launch.json -

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "pathMappings": {
            "your filepath": "${workspaceRoot}",
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following lines solved my problem -

in php.ini -

```
xdebug.remote_port = "9003"  //added this line
```

in launch.json

```
{

"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003    //changed from 9000 to 9003
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9003,  //added this line
        "runtimeExecutable": "D:\\xampp\\PHP\\php.exe"    //added this line
    }
]
}
```