# Xdebug is working but not stopping at breakpoints in VSCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

I'm using XAMPP and have installed Xdebug from [Xdebug Wizard page](https://xdebug.org/wizard), but renamed `php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll` to `php_xdebug.dll`

My php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this extension installed:
[image: this]

When run I get this output in the console:
[image: this]

When I set the listen Xdebug:
[image: this]

And open the program it goes trough the breakpoint:
[image: this]

Comment: You have **Xdebug 3** but php.ini config is for old Xdebug v2. Those settings do almost NOTHING in v3. Go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide and update your config

Comment: Also check this recent question - same story / solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65949240/783119